# Devise: redirect back after unsuccessful login attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

Using Rails 3.1 and Devise 1.4.2

I'm new to using Devise and the site I'm working on has login forms embedded in many pages across the site.  When a user attempts to login and they are rejected, the default behavior is to redirect back to users/sign_in.

I would like to redirect back (to request.referrer), but I can't seem to figure out how/where to make this happen.

I tried overriding the Devise::SessionsController with my own Create action:

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in_and_redirect(resource, request.referrer)
end
```

but this also seems to redirect to users/sign_in.

I have confirmed that my custom SessionsController is receiving the request

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this devise wiki page:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

I think that you can find all necessary information there :)